# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting , during uploading data to web sql server,

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, typeerror, pymysql

```
import pymysql as psl
con6s = psl.connect(host='myhost',database='mydatabase',user='usr',passwd='12345')
c6s = con6s.cursor()
c6s.execute( "INSERT INTO %s (stmp,dat,tm,tc,mc,sd,rp,st,stf,stt) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)" % (str(db)), (stmp,dat,tm,tc,mc,sd,rp,st,stf,stt))
con6s.commit()
con6s.close()
```

---

```
File "C:/Users/Bwrl/Desktop/al/Time_wither_server_upload/testdb.py", line 134, in cld_sd (str(db)), (stmp,dat,tm,tc,mc,sd,rp,st,stf,stt))

File "C:\Users\Bwrl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 164, in execute query = self.mogrify(query, args)

File "C:\Users\Bwrl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 143, in mogrify query = query % self._escape_args(args, conn)

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I cross-check all of these variables many times, type of all variables are ok.

Comment: What's the type of `db` ?

Comment: if you write the name of the table directly without %s it gives the same error?

Comment: replacing `?` to `%s` might work

Comment: @CherifOdoo i tried all that , with directly gives db name

Comment: @JkShaw i tried that also.

Comment: @PM2Ring this is sql server

Comment: @JkShaw It would _appear_ to work, but it'd open things up to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Is `db` a string, or is it some other kind of object?

Comment: ty to print `"INSERT INTO %s (stmp,dat,tm,tc,mc,sd,rp,st,stf,stt) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)" %  str(db) ` and see what is giving you

Comment: what are the types of : (stmp,dat,tm,tc,mc,sd,rp,st,stf,stt)

Comment: @PM2Ring db is a name of  table

Comment: @CherifOdoo  starting with first variable string,string,string,int,int,float,int,int,char,string

Comment: If `db` is a string why are you doing `str(db)` ? And if it's a string, all my versions should work correctly.

Comment: can you post the full code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something wrong with your `execute` call.

You've mixed the `string format` with `execute args` by using the `%`.

You need replace the `%` to `,` and move the `string format` out by using the `string.format`.

```
 sql_cmd = """INSERT INTO 
               {} (stmp,dat,tm,tc,mc,sd,rp,st,stf,stt) 
                   VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)""".format(table_name)

 c6s.execute(sql_cmd, (stmp,dat,tm,tc,mc,sd,rp,st,stf,stt))
```

The prototype for `cursor.execute`

```
 cursor.execute(sql, (args,))
```

Here is the [official docs](http://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/examples.html)

Answer (score 1):

In that `.execute` call you should only be passing `db` to the `%` string interpolation operator, but Python thinks you are trying to interpolate those other variables too, so you need to change the parentheses:

```
c6s.execute(("INSERT INTO %s (stmp,dat,tm,tc,mc,sd,rp,st,stf,stt) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)" % str(db)), (stmp,dat,tm,tc,mc,sd,rp,st,stf,stt))
```

And if `db` is a string that can be simplified to

```
c6s.execute(("INSERT INTO %s (stmp,dat,tm,tc,mc,sd,rp,st,stf,stt) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)" % db), (stmp,dat,tm,tc,mc,sd,rp,st,stf,stt))
```

although I'd be inclined to split it up to make it easier to read:

```
cmd = ("INSERT INTO %s (stmp,dat,tm,tc,mc,sd,rp,st,stf,stt) "
    "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)" % db)
c6s.execute(cmd, (stmp,dat,tm,tc,mc,sd,rp,st,stf,stt))
```

Comment: the error now is : TypeError: not enough arguments for format string